# Fixing asymmetrical neatline in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

I have made a map with neatline but when I print preview it or print to file the gap between neatline and one edge is larger than the other 3 edges.

I have had this problem before but I can never remember how to fix it. I am pretty clueless in Layout View.

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

[image: here's an image of the upper frame. Its the wide right side margin I'm talking about]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your data frame isn’t sized symmetrically/centered on your page. Select the data frame to bring up the corner anchors, then resize.

Comment: I've tried everything including that.

Comment: And what happens when you do? No corner anchors appear?

Comment: depends on what you mean by corner anchor. If you mean the squares on the corners, yes they appear. Moving those do nothing. If you mean an "X", no.  The dotted line in the image is the printer margins, and I know way of moving that. The neatline is inserted in relation to the printer margins.